# Inheritance hierarchy casting for on-demand allocating pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, language-lawyer, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on an asset management library. One of its major features are Lazy and Firm pointers that delegate asset loading and construction to the reference counter it retrieved from the asset manager. The FirmPtr is used to access the allocated and loaded asset, while LazyPtr is just a handle that is used to initialize FirmPtrs and doesn't require the asset to exist yet. So basically, lazy allocation. Now I want to add a standard-compliant and performant method of casting between pointers to inherited class objects.

This is a stripped down version of the code.

```
template <AssetLike Asset> class ReferenceCounter {
    std::size_t m_strongcount;
    std::size_t m_weakcount;

  protected:
    Asset *p_asset;

    virtual void ensure_loaded_impl() = 0;
    virtual void allow_unload_impl() = 0;
    virtual void forget_impl() = 0;

  public:
    Asset &hold() {
        // ...
        return *p_asset;
    }
    void release() {
        // ...
    }
    void weak_hold() {
        // ...
    }
    void weak_release() {
        // ...
    }
};


template <AssetLike Asset> class LazyPtr {
    using DecAsset = std::decay_t<Asset>;
    using RefCtr = ReferenceCounter<DecAsset>;

    friend class FirmPtr<DecAsset>;

    RefCtr *m_p_ctr;

  public:
    LazyPtr() : m_p_ctr(nullptr) {}
    LazyPtr(RefCtr &ctr) : m_p_ctr(&ctr) { ctr.weak_hold(); }
    LazyPtr(const LazyPtr<Asset> &other) : LazyPtr(*other.m_p_ctr) {}
    LazyPtr(const FirmPtr<Asset> &other) : LazyPtr(*other.m_p_ctr) {}

    ~LazyPtr() {
        if (m_p_ctr)
            m_p_ctr->weak_release();
    }
};

/**
 * @brief A strong reference to an asset. Ensures the asset is loaded.
 * @note Can be used like a pointer to the asset.
 */
template <AssetLike Asset> class FirmPtr {
    using DecAsset = std::decay_t<Asset>;
    using RefCtr = ReferenceCounter<DecAsset>;

    friend class LazyPtr<DecAsset>;

    RefCtr *m_p_ctr;
    Asset *m_p_asset;

  public:
    FirmPtr() : m_p_ctr(nullptr) {}
    FirmPtr(RefCtr &ctr) : m_p_ctr(&ctr), m_p_asset(&ctr.hold()) {}
    FirmPtr(const FirmPtr<Asset> &other) : FirmPtr(*other.m_p_ctr) {}
    FirmPtr(const LazyPtr<Asset> &other) : FirmPtr(*other.m_p_ctr) {}

    ~FirmPtr() {
        if (m_p_ctr)
            m_p_ctr->release();
    }

    Asset &operator*() const { return *m_p_asset; }
    Asset &operator->() const { return *m_p_asset; }
};
```

After this I implement an AssetManager that privately uses a fully implemented ReferenceCounter that allocates and loads assets depending on its loading and caching scheme. Which manager is used depends on its use-case. For each Asset type an AbstractAssetManager is derived from by complete AssetManager types, and can be used in its place dynamically. This is important for modularity. So the ReferenceCounters all share the general counting logic, but delegate the actual loading behavior by calling ensure_loaded_impl() and  allow_unload_impl() when the strong counter drops/raises from zero.

Now I want to implement casting from a LazyPtr to and from a LazyPtr while ensuring the Derived class object gets created when initializing a FirmPtr later while the FirmPtr points to Base.

Obviously, I have to make the ReferenceCounter<> more general. One idea was to make ReferenceCounter return a char* and keep track of the offset between the type of object returned by the ReferenceCounter and the type of object referenced by the LazyPtr. That would work for non-virtual unambiguous inheritances, but even then I'm not sure if it's standard. Alternatively, I could use pointers to casting functions, but this could result in a chain of capturing casting functions for something that could theoretically be done with compile-time address shifts. Is there a performant and standard-compliant way to do this?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to do, but don't `std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr` be used?

Comment: No, the weak_ptr becomes nullptr when the obect is deallocated. The object can't be reconstructed and then retrieved from said weak_ptr. Here the WeakPtr is initialized first, and later used to initialize a StrongPtr which also allocates the asset.

Comment: "*So basically, lazy allocation.*" Then maybe you shouldn't name them after the standard library strong and weak pointers. That naming convention suggests behavior that is not provided by those types. Also, the thing you want to do doesn't make sense. Your "weak pointer" may or may not refer to an already loaded asset. If you try to cast it to a derived type, that won't be possible if the asset is loaded, since you cannot convert a complete object that exists into a derived class instance of that object.

Comment: Where in your scheme does the actual loading occur? What determines the type of the asset that gets loaded? Can you show an example of how this machinery is supposed to be used, what the casting you are talking about would look like in the calling code?

Comment: Yes, it would be a good idea to rename them which I will do. Why wouldn't I be able to convert an existing object into a derived type? That sounds like a normal downcast. Obviously, I don't plan on casting from Base to Derived if the object wasn't allocated as Derived.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I updated the explanation with the loading scheme. Unfortunately to precisely show how it works I would have to basically paste the entire repo. Not sure if links would be allowed in comments.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. In order to cast from, say, `FirmPtr<Dervied>` to `FirmPtr<Base>`, you need to somehow obtain an instance of `ReferenceCounter<Base>` given `ReferenceCounter<Derived>`. But these are two unrelated classes; clearly the same object can't be both. I don't see how an upcast would work, let alone the downcast. I imagine you would need type erasure in there somewhere.

Comment: Yes, that's the crux of the issue. What I need is a type erasure on which casting operations can be performed without instances of those types, so the accumulated casting of lazy pointers can later be performed on a type-erased pointer to an instance of Derived.

Comment: I still think that `std::shared_ptr` might be used, but hard to go further without minimal repro. Too many possible "allocation" policies possible.

Comment: The goal is to load resources on demand, and allow the manager's algorithms to decide when to unload/keep resources based on the frequency of usage, loading cost and other factors. The full codebase is here: https://github.com/LMauricius/DynAsMa . The current manager algorithms are simple, just to test the waters for future implementation.